# Arithimetic operation before aggregation

Tags: python, django, orm, aggregate

I have this table in my models.py:

```
class Vendas(models.Model):
    ''' Contem informacoes sobre venda realizadas. '''

    purchaser_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    purchase_count = models.IntegerField()
    merchant_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    merchant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And this view:

```
def success(request):
    ''' Pagina de retorno para quando o arquivo eh carregado com sucesso! '''

    total = ....
    return render(request, "file_upload/success.html", locals())
```

In my view I need to multiply the fields `item_price` and `purchase_count` and after that `SUM` them.

In SQL it would be something like `SELECT SUM(item_price*purchase_count) FROM Vendas;` but using `objects.raw` is also not working.

Could someone help me with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`QuerySet.extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) and [`QuerySet.values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

```
total = Vendas.objects.extra(select={
    'price': 'sum(item_price * purchase_count)'
}).values_list('price', flat=True)[0]
```

Example:

```
>>> Vendas.objects.create(item_price='5.0', purchase_count=1)
<Vendas: Vendas object>
>>> Vendas.objects.create(item_price='15.0', purchase_count=5)
<Vendas: Vendas object>
>>> Vendas.objects.extra(select={
...     'price': 'sum(item_price * purchase_count)'
... }).values_list('price', flat=True)[0]
80
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but I actually don't know exactly what means the parts of the `.extra` object.

Comment: @LucasRezende, Did you follow the link in the answer? You will find the documentation which contains detailed information about `extra`.

Comment: Actually I haven't noticed it was a link, but as I know now, I will look after it to understand in details. Again, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would add a calculated property to each item and then sum them all in the view if you need that also.

```
class Vendas(models.Model):
    ''' Contem informacoes sobre venda realizadas. '''

    purchaser_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    purchase_count = models.IntegerField()
    merchant_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    merchant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def _this_total(self)
        return self.item_price*self.purchase_count
    this_total = property(_this_total)

def success(request):
    ''' Pagina de retorno para quando o arquivo eh carregado com sucesso! '''
    objects = <your query for objects here>
    total = sum([i.this_total for i in objects])
    return render(request, "file_upload/success.html", locals())
```